# How do I add space between two divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a webpage, but I'm a total HTML/CSS newbie. I want the following format:

A top half, and a bottom half.

The top half contains 6 big boxes, organized into two columns of 3 boxes.

The bottom half contains some other content, whatever I want.

Right now I (somehow) have it working, but the only thing is the "bottom_half" is too close to the "top_half" -- I just want to add a bit more of a margin in between. But when I tried doing that weird things would happen and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's an outline of my html layout:

```
<div class="top_half">
  <div class="left_half">
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 1 content -->
     </div>
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 2 content -->
     </div>
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 3 content -->
     </div>
   </div> <!-- left-half -->
   <div class="right_half">
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 4 content -->
     </div>
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 5 content -->
     </div>
     <div class="big_box">
        <!-- box 6 content -->
     </div>
   </div> <!-- right-half -->
 </div> <!-- top-half -->

 <div class="bottom_half">
    <!-- bottom-half content -->
 </div>
```

My CSS for top and bottom half look like this:

```
.top_half {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background: lightgreen 
}

.bottom_half {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background: lightyellow;
}
```

Oddly, the top_half div is just a pretty tiny bar at the top of the page, and bottom_half div is taking basically the entire page.

Is my layout bad? Should I be doing it differently? I really have no experience with this at all, so I'm learning as I go along.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Fixed some typos. Take a look at this to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/d7ejv3ad/3/
^^ why aren't the grey boxes staying inside the green bar???

Comment: You have .bottom_half in the CSS but .bottom-half in the html.

Comment: I suggest a vote to close as this error is caused by typos.

Comment: Crap -- sorry, those typos aren't in my actual code, but they're in the code that I copied over to this site!  Same problem even with typos fixed! (I edited original post)

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d7ejv3ad/

HTML

```
<main>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
      <div class="boxes"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
main > div:first-child {
    height: 50vh;
    width: auto;
    background: lightgreen 
}
  main > div:first-child > div { display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 49%; }
    main > div:first-child .boxes {
      margin: 2.5% 0 0 2.5%;
      width: 28%;
      height: 28%;
      background: #fff;
    }

main > div:last-child {
    height: 50vh;
    width: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background: lightyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typing error in second line of HTML code `<div class="left_half>` this should be like `<div class="left_half">`
additionally add this one line in your CSS

```
.big_box{display:inline;}
```

Comment: I fixed the typos but the same things keeps happening. I added the display:inline part and the whole thing sort of spazzes out. I don't understand what's wrong with my logic.

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankurp/y23b3Lta/). Is that what you want...